# How to get PCM data from an mp4 file without converting to wav

Tags: c#, wav, mp4, naudio, pcm

I am attempting to get PCM data from mp4 files without converting to a wav file, so that I can perform FFT.  I am currently using NAudio to perform this and AForge for FFT, but I am open to using other libraries to do this.

The output values when applying FFT to mp4 when compared to wav is massively different and incorrect due to it reading the values from an mp4 not a wav.

Here's the million dollar question - how would I get the pcm values from an mp4 file without converting it to a wav, which would allow for FFT to output the correct values?

This is the code I currently have in C#:

```
public void PCMdata()
    {
        //create media foundation reader to read the AAC encoded file
        using (MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(@"M:\Practice\Sound_Recording\y.mp4"))
        // resample the file to PCM with same sample rate, channels and bits per sample
        using (ResamplerDmoStream resampledReader = new ResamplerDmoStream(reader, new WaveFormat(reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, reader.WaveFormat.Channels)))
            pcm.Add(resampledReader.ToString());


        foreach (Object r in pcm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("STARTING PCM DATA METHOD ");

        System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"M:\Practice\Sound_Recording\y.mp4");
        wave = new byte[WaveFile.Length];
        data = new Double[(wave.Length - 44) / 4]; //shifting the headers out of the PCM data;
        WaveFile.Read(wave, 0, Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 1)
        {
            //16 bit sample rate
            data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, i) / 65536.0;
            //Console.WriteLine(" I " + data[i].ToString());
        }
 }
public void fftCalc()
    {
        complex = new Complex[16384];

        for (int i = 0; i < complex.Length; i++)
        {
            Complex tmp = new Complex(data[i], 0);
            complex[i] = tmp;
        }


        //run FFT
        FourierTransform.FFT(complex, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward);


        //print result and determine the amplitute
        for (int i = 0; i < complex.Length; i+=1)
        {
            //calculate the decibel 
            decibel = (20 * (Math.Log10(complex[i].Magnitude)));
            decibelCount.Add(decibel);
        }

        decibelTotal = decibelCount.Sum();
        average = decibelTotal / complex.Length;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about here. MP4 doesn't support PCM, and you're trying to read the file as if it were raw PCM. You need to decode whatever format is in the MP4. Since you're already using `MediaFoundationReader`, what exactly is your problem? Just use `reader.Read` to get the PCM data. That's really the only thing `MediaFoundationReader` does :)

Comment: @Luaan Thanks, but just two questions - how would I implement reader.Read and how would I decode the mp4 file? :)

Comment: @Luaan The exact problem is, since I am trying to get the PCM from an MP4 file it is giving me massively different results when performing FFT compared to if I was to perform FFT on a wav file.

Comment: The Media Foundation handles decoding the MP4; you just need to ask it to do that. Instead of reading the PCM data from the `FileStream`, do the same thing through the `MediaFoundationReader` (or rather, keep reading until there's no more data left - `Read` returns how many bytes have been read, if that's less than the bytes requested, you're done). If that still gives you weird results, you may be using wrong PCM format (e.g. different bits per sample, rate, channels...) - that's where resampling comes in.

Comment: @Carsey to help yourself and others if you solved your question you should post it here an answer then checkmark it ... its the give and take